# lstat and ls permissions output is somehow differs

Tags: c, file, unix, permissions

I'm trying to rewrite ls function with some of its flags, currently I'm implementing [-l] flag but output about permissions from original ls and lstat are different

Here is my code

```
void mx_strmode(mode_t mode, char * buf) {
  const char chars[] = "rwxrwxrwx";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    buf[i] = (mode & (1 << (8-i))) ? chars[i] : '-';
  }
  buf[9] = '\0';
}

int main(int ac, char **av) {
    t_flags flags = mx_get_flags(ac, av);
    char *dir_name = get_dir_name(ac, av);
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    dir = opendir(dir_name);
    if (!dir) {
        perror("diropen");
        exit(1);
    };

    struct stat s_stat;
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        lstat(entry->d_name, &s_stat);
        char buf_perm[10];
        mx_strmode(s_stat.st_mode, buf_perm);
        printf("%s  %s\n", buf_perm , entry->d_name);

    };

    closedir(dir);
}
```

And here is what i get from ls and my program. I'm opening directory that doesn't contain my executable(may be it's a root of a problem)

```
>drwxr-xr-x   3 fstaryk  4242   102 Jan  3 17:27 .
>drwxr-xr-x  11 fstaryk  4242   374 Jan 18 17:40 ..
>-rw-r--r--   1 fstaryk  4242  4365 Jan 18 17:40 main.c

>rwxr-xr-x    .
>rwx------    ..
>rwx------    main.c
```

Comment: Check the return value of `lstat` (and any other library calls you might not be checking)

Comment: @Mat , lstat actually returns -1 on main.c but I don't know why, and info for ".." is still incorrect

Comment: Print out `dentry->d_name` (and perhaps the current directory to make it clearer).

Comment: @Mat output through perror is 
>lstat: No such file or directory

NAME IS main.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered from adding the error checking as suggested in comments, you're getting issues with 'No such file or directory'. This is because `lstat()` resolves relative paths like the filenames in `struct dirent` objects starting from the current working directory, which is *not* the directory you're trying to list the files of.

Luckily, modern unix/linux systems have a function [`fstatat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstatat.html) that lets you specify a directory to use as the base of relative paths, and you can get the required directory descriptor from a `DIR` struct with `dirfd()`.

Simplified example of using it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(void) {
  DIR *d = opendir("test/");
  if (!d) {
    perror("opendir");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  int dfd = dirfd(d); // Get the directory file descriptor for use with fstatat()
  if (dfd < 0) {
    perror("dirfd");
    closedir(d);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  struct dirent *entry;
  while ((entry = readdir(d))) {
    if (entry->d_name[0] == '.') {
      // Skip dotfiles
      continue;
    }

    struct stat s;
    // Resolve filenames relative to the directory being scanned
    // and don't follow symlinks to emulate lstat()'s behavior
    if (fstatat(dfd, entry->d_name, &s, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) < 0) {
      perror("fstatat");
      closedir(d);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%s: %ld\n", entry->d_name, (long)s.st_size);
  }

  closedir(d);
  return 0;
}
```

On older OSes that lack the `*at()` functions, you'd have to resort to creating a string holding the directory name + filename (With `snprintf()` or whatever) and use that as an argument to `lstat()`.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped a lot